# get reports from elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, report, kibana

We use Elastic to enable on-site search for a client. We are crawling the entire site with NutchCrawler and indexing it all on the Elastic server.
Now I need to create reports that will show which terms are searched most often and in what period, and I need to present all this in the form of a diagram.

I'm trying to get such a report through Kibana, but so far it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried ? We need more details with what you are struggling with.

Comment: This is quite new to me, I thought that through Kibana I would be able to generate a report on what terms were searched for in a certain period, for example:

from 14.11.2022. until 17.11.2022. the following terms were searched:

1. test - 45 times;
2. task - 128 times;
3. work - 12 times;
and so.

Of course, it should be in the form of a table. Maybe I'm generally wrong with this so if you have any suggestions it would help me a lot.

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow what you are wanting to do, but it sounds like you are wanting to create dashboards in Kibana for visualization. Said dashboards can also be used for report generation.

Comment: I am trying to get a report from Elastic which terms were searched for and how many times in a certain period. As I said, I'm new to this and I don't see how I can generate such a report through Kibana. Does elastic even remember which terms came in the requests by default or do I have to emphasize it somehow within the search request... After all, in general, I need advice on what I need to do in order to get such a report in the form of a table.